# Memory leak in C++ where Java is called via JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

There is Java project which is needed to be called from C++ project. So I wrote wrapper. Unfortunately my main language is Java and I didn't do anything in C or C++ for ages. And it seems I did memory leak somewhere in my code, but I have no idea where.

Here is the code of wrapper:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "wrapperJava.h"
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

JNIEnv* env;
jmethodID javaMethodCreate;
jclass javaClass;
int init = 0;
jint rate = 16000;
jint channels = 1;
jint bits = 16;

JNIEnv* create_vm() 
{
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[2];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    args.nOptions = 2;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./router-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:./cp:cp/antlr-2.7.7.jar:cp/aopalliance-1.0.jar:cp/asm-3.3.1.jar:cp/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:cp/bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar:cp/cdi-api-1.1.jar:cp/classmate-1.3.3.jar:cp/commons-codec-1.10.jar:cp/commons-io-2.5.jar:cp/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:cp/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:cp/cryptacular-1.0.jar:cp/cxf-core-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.12.jar:cp/cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.12.jar:cp/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:cp/ehcache-2.10.3.jar:cp/el-api-2.2.jar:cp/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar:cp/guava-16.0.1.jar:cp/h2-1.0.60.jar:cp/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:cp/hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:cp/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.2.Final.jar:cp/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:cp/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:cp/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:cp/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:cp/httpcore-4.4.5.jar:cp/httpmime-4.5.3.jar:cp/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar:cp/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar:cp/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:cp/jain-sip-ri-1.2.324.jar:cp/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar:cp/jasypt-1.9.2.jar:cp/java-support-7.1.1.jar:cp/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:cp/javax.inject-1.jar:cp/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:cp/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar:cp/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar:cp/jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar:cp/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:cp/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:cp/jnotify-0.94.jar:cp/joda-time-2.9.6.jar:cp/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:cp/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:cp/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:cp/logback-classic-1.1.8.jar:cp/logback-core-1.1.8.jar:cp/lombok-1.16.6.jar:cp/neethi-3.0.3.jar:cp/opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar:cp/opensaml-core-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-profile-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-saml-impl-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-security-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-security-impl-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-soap-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xacml-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xacml-impl-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xacml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xacml-saml-impl-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.1.1.jar:cp/opensaml-xmlsec-impl-3.1.1.jar:cp/openws-1.4.2-1.jar:cp/postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:cp/router-schema-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:cp/router-sip-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:cp/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:cp/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:cp/spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-aspects-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-security-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-data-jpa-1.10.6.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-oxm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-security-config-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-ws-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-ws-security-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:cp/spring-xml-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:cp/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:cp/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:cp/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.6.jar:cp/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:cp/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.6.jar:cp/tomcat-juli-8.5.6.jar:cp/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:cp/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:cp/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:cp/wss4j-1.6.19.jar:cp/wss4j-ws-security-common-2.1.4.jar:cp/wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.1.4.jar:cp/xml-resolver-1.2.jar:cp/xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:cp/xmlsec-1.5.8.jar:cp/xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar";
    options[1].optionString = "-Xmx12000m";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    return env;
}

void invoke_main() 
{
    jmethodID mainMethod;
    jclass javaClass;
    jobjectArray applicationArgs;

    javaClass = env->FindClass("org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher");

    mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(javaClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    applicationArgs = env->NewObjectArray(0, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(javaClass, mainMethod, applicationArgs);
}

void init_jni_methods()
{
    javaClass = env->FindClass("com/some/direct/DirectEndpoint");
    javaMethodCreate = env->GetStaticMethodID(javaClass, "createModel", "([BIII)[B");
}

int invoke_create_model(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> data, int length, std::vector<uint8_t> &templ)
{
    jbyteArray baArg = env->NewByteArray(length);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(baArg, 0, length, data.get());
    jbyteArray jValue = NULL;
    jValue = (jbyteArray)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(javaClass, javaMethodCreate, baArg, rate, channels, bits);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(baArg);
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) // check if an exception occurred
    {
        if(jValue != NULL)
        {
           env->DeleteLocalRef(jValue);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t* value = NULL;
    int len = 0;
    if(jValue != NULL)
    {
        len = env->GetArrayLength(jValue);
        value = env->GetByteArrayElements(jValue, JNI_FALSE);
        templ.assign(value, value + len);
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jValue, value, JNI_ABORT);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jValue);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No enough data for creation");
        return -1;
    }
}

ReturnStatus createModel(const Record &record, std::vector<uint8_t> &templ)
{
    ReturnStatus ret = ReturnStatus(ReturnCode::Success, std::string("OK"));
    try
    {
        int i = invoke_create_model(record.data, record.length, templ);
        if( i != 0 )
        {
            ret = ReturnStatus(ReturnCode::CreationError, "Error during creation: no enough data");
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ret = ReturnStatus(ReturnCode::CreationError, "Error during creation: no enough data");
    }
    return ret;
}

ReturnStatus initialize(const std::string &configDir)
{
    if( init ==0 )
    {
        env = create_vm();
        invoke_main();
        init_jni_methods();
        init = 1;
    }
    return ReturnStatus(ReturnCode::Success, "OK");
}
```

At first initialize is called and then createModel. Both calls are from outer project where record and templ arguments ara managed.

There are no memory leaks in Java as Java code works in production with thousands calls. Project with this wrapper crashes after thousand and a half iterations of createModel call with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/test/app crashed.
```

I have seen a lot of similar questions and checked eveything in this wrapper but it didn't give any effect.

Have I forgot to free some memory?

Do I understand right that everything what is created inside Java code and isn't returned to C++ wrapper is managed by Java GC?

**UPD:**
Solved.
The problem is that data of "templ" vector is stored in RAM in outer project. And the heap of outer project is limited to 1.3-2Gb. So after about 1400 iterations where 1Mb data was pushed out every time I got this error.

Comment: From a quick glance through this, it seems okay. Is it possible that there is a leak in your outer project where the other data is being managed?  Have you tried running the app through valgrind or some other memory leak detector?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I just have investigated this issue and wanted to write conclusion.
The problem is that data of templ vector is stored in RAM in outer project. And the heap of outer project is limited to 1.3-2Gb. So after about 1400 iterations where 1Mb data was pushed out every time I got this error.

Comment: Okay - I am voting to close this question as there is no error in the presented code, and it sounds like there really isn't an error in the other code either, just a limitation based on how the outer code is written. With that in mind, this question really isn't a help to anyone in the future.